# Why/When should I use WebSecurity.cs

Tags: c#, webmatrix, formsauthentication

What is the purpose of websecurity.cs, if I can do this using the FormAuthentication and the Membership classes in System.Web.Security why would I need a class to do the same?

Comment: You wouldn't use WebSecurity.cs directly, you'd use the `webmatrix.webdata.websecurity` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebSecurity` is developed for ASP.NET Web Pages. It is a simpler API for accessing the regular `SimpleMembershipProvider`.

You can use it to access the most frequently used security features. So it's not really a replacement for your `FormsAuthentication` and `Membership` classes. Instead it's a wrapper that simplifies development.

The [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) shows how and when to use the class.